# Alguien que halla solucionado este problema submit

Tags: php

tengo un botón submit para cerrar sesión con un name="cerrar",  el type="submit",  cuando ejecuto otro botón con otro nombre diferente se cierra la sesión así tenga otro nombre. mientras tenga submi se mete a esta parte ¿como evitar el problema con submit?

```
 <form action=""  method="POST">                   
                            <p  class="block">
                             <input class="estilosboton" name="cerrar" type="submit" value="1">
                             <input class="estilosboton" name="abrir" 

 <?php  
                            if ($_POST['cerrar']>=1) {    // bien            
                            session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
                            session_destroy(); //destroy the session
                            header("location:/index.php"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
                            exit();
                                }     
                        ?>
                            </p> 
                            </form>
```

Comment: Haz que el título de tu pregunta sea descriptivo: _Alguien que haya*..._ no nos da ninguna pista. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo hacer un archivo y colocar tu código cerrar sesión.

cerrar_session.php

```
   if ($_GET['cerrar']) {    // bien            
                        session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
                        session_destroy(); //destroy the session
                        header("location:/index.php"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
                        exit();
```

Y en el boton colocar lo siguiente

```
<a href="/cerrar_session.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
```

Espero poder ayudarte o aclarado tu duda.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por su respuesta espero mas adelante tambien poder ayudarte. mira esa opción me funciona muy bien  pero tengo otro formulario con otro boton diferente es el siguiente y tambien ejecuta el codigo anterior que esta en otro archivos llamado cerrar_sesion.php lo mas raro es que este es con metodo POST Y EL OTRO ES GET. 
               <form method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
                 </form>