# ¿Por qué un boton afecta a otro. uno que se llama cerrar que ejecuta un codigo que esta en otra pagina y otro que se llama otroboton

Tags: php

El boton que esta dentro del formulario ejecuta un codigo que esta
dentro de un archivo que se llama cerrar_sesion.php. pero el problema es que el otro boton que esta por fuera del formulario que lo quiero usar para otra cosa tambien ejecuta el codigo y ambos se
llaman diferente. lo he puesto en formularios diferentes pero pasa lo mismo ¿porque pasa esto?

```
<form ation="" method="GET">
<button type="submit" name="cerrar" href="cerrar_session.php">Cerrar sesión<button>
</form>
<butto name="otroboton"type="submit">hola</button>

codigo otra pagina
<?php
if ($_GET['cerrar']) {    // bien 
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header("location:/administrador.php"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Pof favor no [dupliques](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465096/alguien-que-halla-solucionado-este-problema-submit) preguntas. Puedes [edit] la primera cuantas veces lo consideres necesario. Por otro lado, aparte de las respuestas que has recibido, toma en cuenta que el elemento de tipo `<button>` en `html` no dispone de ningún atributo llamado `href`, por lo cual, lo que parece que intentas hacer al colocar dicho atributo, es totalmente incorrecto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que en tu formulario, en ambos botones, tienes el atributo `type="submit"`. Al momento en el que des click en cualquiera de los dos, estos botones reaccionarán a enviar el formulario hacia la ruta que hayas establecido en el atributo `action`.

Si lo que necesitas es que tu botón de Cerrar sesión dirija hacia la ruta `cerrar_sesion.php`, primero que nada no necesitas un formulario para hacer esto, lo puedes hacer de diferentes maneras, pero la más sencilla es crear una ruta de enlace (o etiqueta `<a></a>`) que dirija hacia dicha ruta de `cerrar_sesion.php`.

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="cerrar_sesion.php">DA CLICK AQUÍ PARA CERRAR TU SESIÓN</a>
```

Tu código de `cerrar_sesion.php` debe de contener el código que habías proporcionado:

```
<?php
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header("Location: /administrador.php"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
?>
```

Para terminar, hice algunas correciones de sintaxis de tu código, ya que algunas que escribiste estaban mal o les hacían falta letras.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no cerraste bien tu etiqueta `<button>`

Se tiene que cerrar así: `</button>` (A ti te faltó la diagonal).

Esto provoca que el navegador interprete incorrectamente tu HTML.

Lo normal es que un botón no afecte a un formulario si está fuera del mismo.